# image existing on http://website.com but not on www.website.com

Tags: html, image, web

I uploaded an image earlier today and it works fine so long as i do not type www into the URL in front... We have had this problem multiple times and I have no idea why this keeps happening or what I can do to help the problem...

I have tried to access from multiple browsers and computers to see if it's a caching issue but alas, it does not seem to work...

I have used both google AND the stack overflow search functions in an attempt to find someone else with the same problem. Maybe I'm not very good at googling, but I wasn't able to find someone else. I did find qiestions that asked between the differences between using www and not using it, but not a single of them had files that could be located on one of them while not on the other.

Comment: Is it just images that don't load from `www`? Or is it the entire site? I'm guessing it's either an htaccess issue or a DNS zone issue.

Comment: The empty subdomain (website.com) and the www subdomain (www.website.com) are two different sites, but they can be set up to be handled by the same site. Is the web server set up to use the same site for the two names?

Comment: Yes they are set up to be the same site and everything is identic except for a few images... Some of them works only with www and some of them only without...

Answer (score 0):

Which website?

A webserver can respond to

```
domain.com
```

or

```
www.domain.com
```

Some webserver respond to both of them (depending on the configuration), but there is no guarantee.

The keyword is `Webserver Domain Binding` or `Virtual Host` here.

Answer (score 0):

You should open DNS configuration page, in **CNAME Record** section, add more this record:

[image]

Whereby, your images will existing on both **http://www.example.com** and **http://example.com**